# SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event: EndpointFailure

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service

I am getting a error exactly like this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/869fb269-2a6b-4efa-a0e0-c4a829065ca4/load-balancer-error-mesaage

Message:

> SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event:
>   EndpointFailure Process Name: OWSTIMER Process ID: 13708 AppDomain
>   Name: DefaultDomain AppDomain ID: 1 Service Application Uri:
>   urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:d22ed5662d4942098aa7c4d4cda5c5a1#authority=urn:uuid:b57679fac4fc4686afa3862845c1835f&authority=https://server/Topology/topology.svc
>   Active Endpoints: 3 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint:
>   http://server/ProfileService.svc

The thing is that the solution for this error is to stop and start the Managed Metadata Web Service.

But in my case, those are not even started. Is there a negative impact on starting them? Should them be started both in WFE/APP servers?

Comment: what you mean not started? is User Profile Service instance started on failing server?

Comment: User Profile Service is started on WFE and APP. Managed Metadata Web Service is not on any

Comment: Do you have MMS configured in your farm? if yes then it should be start on 1 server atleaset. But the error you posted showing that one of UPA end point failing.

Comment: I noticed, but most solutions I found involved the MMS even for this profile error. Ill check my MMS config

Comment: MMS is started in "Service Applications" but not started on any server in "Services on Server"

Comment: ok, start that will fix MMS issue. if you click on MMS service application in the Manage service application then you will get error.

Comment: I am still getting the profileservice.svc error. User Profile Service is started in 2 WFE servers and 2 APP servers. User Profile Sync Service is started in one APP server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error you mentioned, that indicate us that user profile service instance having the issue on one server.

- Sometime It Is Just a glitch(From network or connection etc) and next moment failing endpoint become active.
- Sometime you have to stop the user profile service instance on that server and start it again to fix. You can do via central admin > system settings > manger services on server> select the server and stop it and start it.
- I also noted, some time an endpoint become orphan.in that case you can stop the profile service instance on bad server, then open IIS...under service make sure no entry exits for the profileservices. Now start it again

Also check the event and ups logs for more clue.

Comment: a follow up question if I may: should User Profile Service run on WFE, APP or both? Thanks